# python winrm Protocol throws WARNING 's how to prevent it?

Tags: python, winrm

i have this code which works great, but it print WARNING and i want to prevent them from showing
as it causing Confusion in logs

```
 try:
        p = Protocol(
            endpoint='http://{}:{}/wsman'.format("10.x.x.4x", "5xxxx"),
            transport='ntlm',
            username='xxxx',
            password='xxxx',
            server_cert_validation='ignore')

        shell_id = p.open_shell()
        command_id = p.run_command(shell_id, command, command_args)
        std_out, std_err, status_code = p.get_command_output(shell_id, command_id)
        p.cleanup_command(shell_id, command_id)
        p.close_shell(shell_id)

        if status_code == 1:
            logger.error("execute_win_command failed: %s %s %s" % (std_out, std_err, status_code))
            return False

        logger.info(
            "execute_win_command success: %s %s %s" % (std_out, connection_map['ip'], connection_map['port']))

    except Exception as err:
        if std_err is not None and status_code is not None and std_out is not None:
            logger.error("execute_win_command  %s %s %s" % (std_out, std_err, status_code))
        logger.error("At %s exception: %s - %s :%s" %
                     ("execute_win_command", current_user.username, repr(err), traceback.format_exc()))
        return False
```

Im getting this :

```
WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Failed to parse headers (url=http://10.x.x.4x:5xxxx/wsman): [StartBoundaryNotFoundDefect(), MultipartInvariantViolationDefect()], unparsed data: ''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 446, in _make_request
    assert_header_parsing(httplib_response.msg)
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\response.py", line 71, in assert_header_parsing
    raise HeaderParsingError(defects=defects, unparsed_data=unparsed_data)
urllib3.exceptions.HeaderParsingError: [StartBoundaryNotFoundDefect(), MultipartInvariantViolationDefect()], unparsed data: ''
WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Failed to parse headers (url=http://10.x.x.4x:5xxxx/wsman): [StartBoundaryNotFoundDefect(), MultipartInvariantViolationDefect()], unparsed data: ''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 446, in _make_request
    assert_header_parsing(httplib_response.msg)
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\response.py", line 71, in assert_header_parsing
    raise HeaderParsingError(defects=defects, unparsed_data=unparsed_data)
urllib3.exceptions.HeaderParsingError: [StartBoundaryNotFoundDefect(), MultipartInvariantViolationDefect()], unparsed data: ''
WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Failed to parse headers (url=http://10.x.x.4x:5xxxx/wsman): [StartBoundaryNotFoundDefect(), MultipartInvariantViolationDefect()], unparsed data: ''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 446, in _make_request
    assert_header_parsing(httplib_response.msg)
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\response.py", line 71, in assert_header_parsing
    raise HeaderParsingError(defects=defects, unparsed_data=unparsed_data)
urllib3.exceptions.HeaderParsingError: [StartBoundaryNotFoundDefect(), MultipartInvariantViolationDefect()], unparsed data: ''
WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Failed to parse headers (url=http://10.x.x.4x:5xxxx/wsman): [StartBoundaryNotFoundDefect(), MultipartInvariantViolationDefect()], unparsed data: ''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 446, in _make_request
    assert_header_parsing(httplib_response.msg)
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\response.py", line 71, in assert_header_parsing
    raise HeaderParsingError(defects=defects, unparsed_data=unparsed_data)
urllib3.exceptions.HeaderParsingError: [StartBoundaryNotFoundDefect(), MultipartInvariantViolationDefect()], unparsed data: ''
WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Failed to parse headers (url=http://10.x.x.4x:5xxxx/wsman): [StartBoundaryNotFoundDefect(), MultipartInvariantViolationDefect()], unparsed data: ''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 446, in _make_request
    assert_header_parsing(httplib_response.msg)
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\response.py", line 71, in assert_header_parsing
    raise HeaderParsingError(defects=defects, unparsed_data=unparsed_data)
urllib3.exceptions.HeaderParsingError: [StartBoundaryNotFoundDefect(), MultipartInvariantViolationDefect()], unparsed data: ''
```

Answer (score 1):

---

---

### Suppress logs using standard python library '*logging*' :

---

Place this code on the top of your existing code to ignore logs from *urllib3*

```
import logging
urllib3_logger = logging.getLogger('urllib3')
urllib3_logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line at your script startup.

```
urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

Also you can do it via environment variable `PYTHONWARNINGS`:

```
export PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore:Failed to parse headers"
```

Comment: where to put it i n the code ? that is urllib3.disable_warnings() ?

Comment: Put it right after your imports, or directly after `import urllib3` line

Comment: i dont have it in my applications it is somewhere in some inner lib I'm using 
so where can i set this line :urllib3.disable_warnings()

Comment: if i put it in the python script where i use the winrm , it still showing me the warrnings